# Why loops shows 5 items in first iteration?

Tags: php

I have the following script php that shows 4 columns in row:

```
$columns = 4;
$template = '';

if (!empty($this->response)) {

    $template.='<div class="container"><div id="comments">';

    $rows = ceil(count($this->response->data) / $columns);

    for ($row = 0; $row < $rows; $row++) {

        $template.='<div class="row">';

        foreach ($this->response->data as $k => $v) {
            if ($k % $rows == $row) {
                $template.='<div class="border col-xs-3">
                        <div class="col-md-4"><a target="_blank" href="'.$v->from->link.'"><img src="'.$v->from->picture->data->url.'"></a></div>
                        <div class="col-md-8"><h4>'.$v->from->name.'</h4><p>'.$v->message.'</p></div>
                </div>';
            }
        }

        $template.='</div>';
    }

    $template.='</div></div>';

}

return $template;
```

It works unstable. At first iteration in loop I get 5 `class="border col-xs-3"` block instead 4.

What do I do wrong?

I expect to get:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="border col-xs-3"></div>
<div class="border col-xs-3"></div>
<div class="border col-xs-3"></div>
<div class="border col-xs-3"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="border col-xs-3"></div>
<div class="border col-xs-3"></div>
<div class="border col-xs-3"></div>
<div class="border col-xs-3"></div>
</div>

....
```

Comment: What is the content of `$this->response`?

Comment: This is object with key `data`. Also if do echo `$rows` I get 7

Comment: `if ($k % $columns== 0) `  - try this

Comment: In this case I get `7 items` in first `row`

Comment: `if ($k <4) {`  try it

Comment: show the data inside `$this->response` and  tell the expected output.

Comment: It makes dublicates in one row

Comment: @Gabala: Then the logic is wrong. You print the variables($k,$columns,$rows,$row) inside `foreach ($this->response->data as $k => $v) ` and make your logic right.

Comment: `foreach ($this->response->data as $k => $v) {
            if ($k <4) {
                $template.='<div class="border col-xs-3">
                        <div class="col-md-4"><a target="_blank" href="'.$v->from->link.'"><img src="'.$v->from->picture->data->url.'"></a></div>
                        <div class="col-md-8"><h4>'.$v->from->name.'</h4><p>'.$v->message.'</p></div>
                </div>';
            }
        }`

Comment: It makes dubliicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$columns = 4;
$template = '';

if (!empty($this->response)) {

    $template.='<div class="container"><div id="comments">';
    $rowCount = $columns;

        foreach ($this->response->data as $k => $v) { 
            if ( $rowCount == $columns ) {   
               $template.='<div class="row">';
            }

            $rowCount--;
            $template.='<div class="border col-xs-3">
                        <div class="col-md-4"><a target="_blank" href="'.$v->from->link.'"><img src="'.$v->from->picture->data->url.'"></a></div>
                        <div class="col-md-8"><h4>'.$v->from->name.'</h4><p>'.$v->message.'</p></div>
                </div>';

        }

        if ($rowCount == 1) {
           $template.='</div>';
           $rowCount = $columns;
        }

    $template.='</div></div>';

}

return $template;
```